# Reason why type inference failed in Kotlin

Tags: oop, generics, kotlin, type-inference

Could someone please help me to wrap my head around the Kotlin compiler behavior?
The intention of the program is to convert the input string to a corresponding type(`BMsg` or `CMsg`)
and print the result in a console.
 
However, I receive the following message from the compiler:

> "Type inference failed. Not enough information to infer parameter T
>   ..."

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper

abstract class classA<T> {
    fun handle(body: String) {
        val result = convertToSpecificMessageType(body) // This line fails
        printResult(result)
        otherImportantStuff()
    }

    abstract fun otherImportantStuff()

    private inline fun <reified T : Any> String.toPayloadObject(): T =
            jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(this, T::class.java)

    private inline fun  <reified T : Any> convertToSpecificMessageType(body: String): T = body.toPayloadObject()
    private fun printResult(result: T) = println("result = $result")
}

class classB : classA<BMsg>() {
    override fun otherImportantStuff() = print("important stuff of class B")
}

class classC : classA<CMsg>() {
    override fun otherImportantStuff() = print("important stuff of class C")
}

sealed class Msg
data class BMsg(val x: String) : Msg()
data class CMsg(val y: Int) : Msg()

fun main() {
    classB().handle("{\"x\" : \"aaa\"}")
    classC().handle("{\"y\" : 5}")
}
```

Despite I found a workaround -  declaring `convertToSpecificMessageType` method as an `abstract`
and override in `classB`/`classC`, I'm wondering (1) what is the reason which makes the compiler to complain 
(2) if there is a way to fix the problem without overriding `convertToSpecificMessageType`?
Thank you in advance!

**P.S.** kotlin version = '1.3.21'

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `<reified T : Any>` in front of your methods (`toPayloadObject` and `convertToSpecificMessageType`) you're introducing a new type parameter `T` for your methods that has no relation to the type parameter of `classA` with the same name `T`.

The method-local declaration of `T` *shadows* the `T` on `classA`.

As a result, when you do `val result = convertToSpecificMessageType(body)` - there is no context at all that Kotlin can use to infer the type from. Although you're in a method in `classA`, the `T` from classA is not used by method `convertToSpecificMessageType`.

The solution?

You can't use a reified type on a class so either:

- you can remove the `<reified T : Any>` parts and pass a class object to the methods
- or you keep it there but you provide context when you invoke the method as in `val result = convertToSpecificMessageType<MyType>(body)` or `val result : MyType = convertToSpecificMessageType(body)`